# Importing gradle project in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I have IntelliJ 12.0 on and gradle 1.2. on Windows 7. When I try to import a build.gradle file I get the following error message in IntelliJ. I am a bit lost here. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
 (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
 Caused by: org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.remote.GradleApiException: 
 Could not fetch model of type 'BasicIdeaProject' using Gradle installation 'C:\Program Files (x86)\gradle-1.2'.
 The newly created daemon process has a different context than expected.
 It won't be possible to reconnect to this daemon. Context mismatch: 
 Java home is different.
 Wanted: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=null,javaHome=c:\program files (x86)\jetbrains     \intellij idea 12.0\jre\jre,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\Nilo\.gradle     \daemon,pid=5144,idleTimeout=null,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:     +HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252]
 Actual: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=d8c5c4bc-5488-42c2-b4b3-28c1d53afacf,javaHome=C:     \Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 12.0\jre,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\Nilo \.gradle\daemon,pid=6880,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252]
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.remote.impl.GradleProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolverImpl.java:61)
... 21 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

my fix: File -> Project Structure -> change the jdk path to not have jre.

I'm not sure how it got there, but it took me *forever* to track down. Perhaps because it picked up settings from a previous bad install.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it might be fixed in 12.1 or 12 EAP: [IDEA-102365](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-102365), [IDEA-89697](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-89697)

Answer (score 2):

Though I did not find the root cause where the different javaHomes have been taken from, at least I found a workaround that worked for me:

Try setting the following in your `gradle.properties` (either in `%USERPROFILE%\.gradle\` or in your project build dir):

```
org.gradle.java.home=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 12.0\jre
```

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ v15.0.6, same problem.

I'm using a JRE that's not the one that is built into IntelliJ.

- I made sure JAVA_HOME was pointing to my JRE, then
- I deleted "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.6\", then
- I restarted IntelliJ.

Now my gradle build scripts work fine from within IntelliJ.